# How to insert a PHP variable in to HTML stored in a JS variable?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to insert the `ButtonSend` var inside my `<input>` part? This way will not work:

```
var ButtonSend = <?php _e('Go!', $this->plugin_slug) ?>;
LangKeys['en']['button'] = '<input v-on:click.prevent="submit" type="button" value="ButtonSend" />';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a string value (from the context of the property name) you need to wrap the PHP output in quotes. Then you can concatenate the value as you would any other:

```js
var ButtonSend = '<?php _e('Go!', $this->plugin_slug) ?>';
LangKeys.en.button = '<input v-on:click.prevent="submit" type="button" value="' + ButtonSend + '" />';
```

Alternatively you could use a template literal to do the concatenation, assuming you don't need IE support:

```
LangKeys.en.button = '<input v-on:click.prevent="submit" type="button" value="${ButtonSend}" />';
```